# How to select features for unsupervised clustering / prediction from a list of ~1000 features?

Tags: clustering, feature-selection

I have some very large data sets from the World Bank on economic performance and I'm trying to analyze if variable A can predict variable B, so am trying to apply

1. Unsupervised clustering to understand the nature of the data, and then
2. use decision tree regressor or neural net to predict B from A (using the usual cross validation or shuffle fold, with train / test sets, etc. etc.).

The problem is that variable A is actually comprised of 900 possible candidates...all the 900 sub-variables form the overall concept of "A". For B, it's the same, about 250 sub-variables that form the overall concept of "B". Given the sheer volume, is there a good way to systematically figure out what's the best combination of the sub-variables in "A" that can predict "B" (or even simply go into the unsupervised clustering to generate a data understanding)? Besides brute force, which I believe is basically an NP-complete problem. ;)

Comment: Have you considered dimensionality reduction?

Comment: Why decision tree regressor or neural net?  Those are very different models that were seemingly chosen at random.

Comment: I don't think you described your data very well. I am imagining 2 columns, one with 900 distinct values and the other with 250.

Comment: @AbrahamHorowitz - yes, but the question is what's the best way to do this dimensionality reduction? I am trying to exactly do what you mentioned...

Comment: @UzumakiNaruto — Have you tried principal component analysis?